# ¿Cómo mostrar varias imágenes en un JFrame y mostrarla?

Tags: java, jframe

Estoy usando Java y necesito mostrar varias imagenes en un Frame, ya logré mostrar pero solo una y necesito varias. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?
Estoy con Netbeans

```
ImageIcon imagen = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\images.jpg");
    JLabel etiqueta = new JLabel(imagen);

    public PruebaImagen() {
        super("Muestra de Imagen en JAVA...");

        getContentPane().add(etiqueta);

        this.setSize(500, 500);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que puedas visualizar varias imagenes, debes crear un JLabel, dejarlo vacio, darle un nombre...

Debes crear Dos JCombobox con las siguientes caracteristicas

Primer JCombo Box (Horario_CMB_Area_De_Trabajo)
Tendra los nombres de las imagenes que se visualizaran...

Ejemplo
Selecciona la opcion model del cuadro de propiedades e ingresa las cadenas de caracteres.

(Nombres dentro del JCombo Box)
Seleccione un Departamento de Trabajo
1. Departamento Comercial / Ventas
2. Departamento de Administracion
3. Departamento de Almacen
4. Departamento de Control de Gestion
5. Departamento de Direccion / Gerencia
6. Departamento de Finanzas
7. Departamento de Logistica

Comment: Esa es una parte del codigo, puedo ayudarte a mejorar con el Diseño De Las Interfaces Graficas...Estos son mis datos personales.

correo Electrocnico:
ing.gsalmerong@uagrovirtual.mx
Numero: 7474998002

Answer (score 0):

Para poder visualizar varias imagenes en un JFrame puedes **utilizar un JPanel** e **ir añadiendo a dicho Jpanel las imagenes**, entonces **añadir el JPanel al JFrame** y mostrar este último. Este código te puede servir de ejemplo:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
class demo 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame f=new JFrame("Web layout...");
         ImageIcon imagen1 = new ImageIcon ("imagenes/a.png");
         ImageIcon imagen2 = new ImageIcon ("imagenes/b.png");
         ImageIcon imagen3 = new ImageIcon ("imagenes/c.png");
         ImageIcon imagen4 = new ImageIcon ("imagenes/d.png");
         ImageIcon imagen5 = new ImageIcon ("imagenes/e.png");
         ImageIcon imagen6 = new ImageIcon ("imagenes/f.png");
        //declare my jlabels...........
        JLabel label1, label2, label3, label4,label6, label5;
        // Set up first subpanel
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(400, 400));
        panel.setBackground (Color.cyan);
        label1 = new JLabel ("a", imagen1, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label2 = new JLabel ("b",imagen2, SwingConstants.LEFT);
        label3 = new JLabel ("c", imagen3, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label4 = new JLabel ("d", imagen4, SwingConstants.LEFT);
        label5 = new JLabel ("e", imagen5, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label6 = new JLabel ("f", imagen6, SwingConstants.LEFT);
        panel.add (label1);
        panel.add (label2);
        panel.add (label3);
        panel.add (label4);
        panel.add (label5);
        panel.add (label6);
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.add(panel);
        f.setVisible(true);  

        }
}
```